# How to remove color of target area from uiimage?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimage, uicolor

i am having a image view with image, if user touch on a specific area, color of that area should be removed.

See the below image for reference.

In the reference image target area is first leaf in image 1, and in image 2 we can see first leaf color is removed.

Anyone knows how to do this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: A few criticisms. First, in many ways, the removal of a color *does not* equate to white. (Sometimes, black, sometimes, green/blue.) So what *specifically do you expect? Second, what have you tried? Do you have some code we can help you with?

Comment: i don't have any code can you help or suggest any solution   @dfd

Comment: I'd suggest googling "area flood fill"  the first response is, of course, the wikipedia page.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill  Many algorithms there, pick one.

Comment: Not really. Why no code? Are you saying you haven't tried anything? What about my other question. UIColor, like most colors, have 4 components: RGBA. Removing the R *does not* mean white. What are you looking for?

Comment: i have tried using [github.com/chinatndave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill](http://github.com/chinatndave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill) but i am not getting desired result, it is replacing color of target area with black color i want to replace target area color with clear color   @dfd